# Magento - overlay a 'clearance' icon on all products in clearance category

Tags: magento

I want to overlay a 'Clearance' icon on all products which are listed in my clearance category.

The user will obviously be browsing the products under the other categories it appears in.

So I figure when listing the products on each page I need to check which other categories it belongs in, and add some additional markup if it is in 'clearance'.

I am fine with styling it afterward. Even if I can just add 
    `<div class="clearance-tag"></div>` 
below the product image I can assign it a background image and float/position it to where I need.

I'm afraid with Magento I often know roughly what code/logic I want to write, just no idea where to write it.

Can anyone help?
I'm using Magento 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it. Here's how.

1) Copy the files from base:

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

to your custom design package.

**app/design/frontend/*mydesignpackage*/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
app/design/frontend/*mydesignpackage*/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

In **list.phtml** find the lines (around line 86)

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

And immediately after, insert the following code:

```
<?php 
//get all categories associated with this product
$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
$clearance_category = 134; //clearance category id

if(in_array($clearance_category, $categories)) {
    $clearancetag='<div class="clearance-tag">Clearance</div>';
}
else {
    $clearancetag='';
}
?>
```

Further down find the really long line:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

And insert your variable just before the closing `</a>` tag:

```
null, true) ?>" /><?php echo $clearancetag ?></a>
```

That takes care of the Product grid.

Next To show the Clearance icon in Product View. I'm just going to show it next to the description.

In **view.phtml** 
Find the lines:

```
 <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
 <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
```

And immediately after paste the code:

```
<?php 
//get all categories associated with this product
$categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
$clearance_category = 134; //clearance category id
if(in_array($clearance_category, $categories)) {
    echo '<div class="clearance-tag">CLEARANCE</div>';
}
?>
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways of doing this and hardcoding your category id isn't ideal. But it worked for me and hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

First get category Id's of the product then loop this array;

```php
<?php
/* get categories from product */  
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();  

/* looping the array of the category ids */  
foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {  
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);  
?>
```

this code give you categoryId's, if product has a specified category then you can set some css class.

Answer (score 0):

View the source of your category page, the body element should already have a few useful class names like `category-clearance` (deduced from the URL key) and you can use that directly in your stylesheet. Add the DIV element as you have already proposed then style it with:

```
.category-clearance .clearance-tag {
    background-image: url(etc...)
}
```

---

This is an incredibly useful trick and the class names are automatic on nearly all pages. For example the home page is served by the CMS module so gets a class name `cms-home` - This means you can create styles that are specific to the home page.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still uncertain how to add the DIV element to the markup of each individual product. 
Scenario is: The user is browsing the category 'Furniture'. An icon appears next to some of the products indicating that they also appear in the 'clearance' category. 
Effectively I'm tagging 'clearance' items by assigning them to a category called 'clearance' and need to find a way of highlighting those items regardless of which category page you are on. 
What you've described is still useful to know and it's going to help me with doing various other things, so thanks still.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I shall have to think about it some more.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with jQuery. This is pretty easy for someone to insert into their site under System>Configuration>Display>HTML Head into the Miscellaneous Scripts field.

This works on finding products that have a was and a now price. I'm not familiar enough with the different versions of Magento to know whether you would need to change the selectors, but the principle should work in most environments.

```
<style>
    .special-tag {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    .slider-products .special-tag {
        display: none;
    }
    .special-tag-product {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 33%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.item-content-wrapper').has('.special-price').append('<img src = "yourimage.png" class = "special-tag"/>');
        $('.product-image').append(
        $('.product-shop').has('.special-price').length ? '<img src = "yourimage_big.png" class = "special-tag-product"/>' : ""
        );
     });
</script>
```

The .slider-products class is specific to my site, and you may not need that styling.